# Difference between random forest and random tree algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

please I need a clarification on random tree and random forest classification algorithm. please if there is any book or site that gives a detailed explanation, kindly suggest.

Comment: @cel I did I did read and understood it but I just wanted a definite explanation for random tree so I can analyse them side by side in weka.

Comment: According to wikipedia a suitable definition of a random tree is: `In mathematics and computer science, a random tree is a tree or arborescence that is formed by a stochastic process.`  I am not sure how comparing to a random forrest classifier should work. That's like trying to compare a car to a vehicle.

Comment: I don't know the exact definitions of "arborescence" and "stochastic process" but taking their intuitive meaning, a Random Forest is an ensemble (collection / team) of Decision Trees, which can be considered random trees if there is some element of randomness in the tree construction -- i.e. training each tree in the forest on a random subset of the dataset, as is done in the Random Forest algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

The comparison between the two is a bit pointless because Random Forest is a method of combining multiple Random Trees (thus - Forest) into one big classifier using even more randomization (selection of random samples with replacement for training each tree plus random selection of features which tree can use to perform split). In other words - RF is an ensemble method **usually** applied to Random Tree. There is no point in comparing them as comepetetice methods because they are not. Random Forest should be compared with other ensemble methods such as AdaBoost etc. and Random Tree with basic, simple classifiers such as Perceptron (although it is from different family of models).

Answer (score 3):

Completing the previous answer, I would recommend the following books to better understand how random forest work:

- *Decision Forests* from A. Criminisi and J. Shotton, very good
  theoretical explanations and illustrations
- *The elements of statistical learning*, T. Hastie

and if you cannot find these books, I would also recommend:

- the original article of Leo Breiman on RF
- the slides and presentations that you can find there :
  http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/decisionforests/

Answer (score 0):

> It's not that complex if you understand Random tree, a Random forest
>   will be simpler which is nothing but combination of multiple Random
>   tree(Decision tree if I am correct)
>
> for better understanding you can go through Ensembled models Averaging
>   method(bagging and Random forest) if you are pretty sure with
>   Ensembled techniques then you are almost master in Random Forest
>   part(I Recommend YouTube Videos). Happy Learning :)

Answer (score -3):

1) Random Forests 
Random forests is a idea of the general technique of random decision forests that are an ensemble learning technique for classification, regression and other tasks, that control by constructing a multitude of decision trees at training time and outputting the class that is the mode of the classes (classification) or mean prediction (regression) of the individual trees. Random decision forests accurate for decision trees' habit of overfitting to their training set. The first algorithm for random decision forests was created by Tin Kam Ho using the random subspace method which, in Ho's formulation, is a way to implement the "stochastic discrimination" approach to classification proposed by Eugene Kleinberg. An extension of the algorithm was developed by Leo Breiman[5] and Adele Cutler,[2] and "Random Forests" is their trademark[3].The extension combines Breiman's "bagging" idea and random selection of features, introduced first by Ho and later independently by Amit and Geman[4] in order to construct a collection of decision trees with controlled variance. 
2)
 Random Tree Random Tree is a supervised Classifier; it is an ensemble learning algorithm that generates lots of individual learners. It employs a bagging idea to construct a random set of data for constructing a decision tree. In standard tree every node is split using the best split among all variables. In a random forest, every node is split using the best among the subset of predicators randomly chosen at that node. Random trees have been introduced by Leo Breiman and Adele Cutler.The algorithm can deal with both classification and regression problems. Random trees is a group (ensemble) of tree predictors that is called forest. The classification mechanisms as follows: the random trees classifier gets the input feature vector, classifies it with every tree in the forest, and outputs the class label that received the majority of “votes”. In case of a regression, the classifier reply is the average of the responses over all the trees in the forest. Random Trees are essentially the combination of two existing algorithms in Machine Learning: single model trees are merged with Random Forest ideas. Model trees are decision trees where every single leaf holds a linear model which is optimised for the local subspace explained by this leaf. Random Forests have shown to improve the performance of single decision trees considerably: tree diversity is created by two ways of randomization[4,6,11]. First the training data is sampled with replacement for each single tree like in Bagging. Secondly, when growing a tree, instead of always computing the best possible split for each node only a random subset of all attributes is considered at every node, and the best split for that subset is computed. Such trees have been for classification Random model trees for the first time combine model trees and random forests. Random trees uses this produce for split selection and thus induce reasonably balanced trees where one global setting for the ridge value works across all leaves, thus simplifying the optimization procedure. [1] [2] [3] [4]

[1]N. Landwehr, M. Hall, and E. Frank, ―Logistic model trees,‖ Mach. Learn., vol. 59, no. 12, pp. 161-205, 2005. 
[2]Breiman Leo (2001). "Random Forests". Machine Learning 45 (1): 5–32.
[3] Liaw, Andy (16 October 2012). “Documentation for R package random forest”. Retrieved 15 March 2013. 
 [4]  U.S. trademark registration number 3185828, registered 2006/12/19. 
[5]Wikipedia contributors, ―Random tree,‖ Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Wikimedia Foundation, 13-Jul- 2014

Comment: This wall of text is really not helpful. You obviously copied and pasted it from somewhere, so please consider posting a link to that instead, as well as a summary that answers the question. If you think that is too difficult given the broad question, you can always flag it and not answer.

Comment: Please quote your sources if you really think you need to poorly copy & paste